# NeoDash error: No SSO providers found or present. Make sure that config.json contains a correct discovery URL

Tags: docker, neo4j

I am trying to set the Google OAuth for [NeoDash](https://neo4j.com/labs/neodash/) running in a docker container. I followed the documentation, and am getting the error:

> No SSO providers found or present. Make sure that config.json contains a correct discovery URL. This is currently set to https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

[image]

Here are the env vars I used for docker:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -p 5005:5005 \
    -e ssoEnabled=true \
    -e ssoDiscoveryUrl="https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" \
    -e standalone=true \
    -e standaloneProtocol="neo4j" \
    -e standaloneHost="neodash.skyinit.com" \
    -e standalonePort="7687" \
    -e standaloneDatabase="neo4j" \
    -e standaloneDashboardName="My Dashboard" \
    -e standaloneDashboardDatabase="dashboards" \
    nielsdejong/neodash
```

Can anyone support me to solve this? I am really stuck at this point.